# Remove default splash screen in phonegap blackberry 10

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10

I am developing blackberry app using phonegap and webworks.Default splash screen appears while opening my app.how to remove that default splash screen and upload my own???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Splash Screens for the BlackBerry 10 Platform

1) Make your custom image with following name.

- splash-1280x768.png (1280×768 pixels)
- splash-720x720.png (720×720 pixels)
- splash-768x1280.png (768×1280 pixels)

2) Replace all images into the project's res/screen/blackberry10 directory.

Comment: I didn find any res folder..i have created blackberry project using webworks SDK.